# How to split array values into to new separate arrays in Perl?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, split, push

I'am a beginner in learning perl.
What I'm trying to do here is to split the array `@value` and insert it into a new array. my problem is, I do not know exactly how to make my coding to run in loop and get my desired result.

Is it possible to get the desired result using this method or is there any other alternative/way to get the same result?

My code is as below;

```
my @separated = ();
my @separated1 = ();
my @separated2 = ();
my @separated3 = ();
my $counter = 0;
my @values = "aaa 111 AAA bbb 222 BBB ccc 333 CCC ddd 444 DDD";

foreach (@values) {
my @separated = split(' ', $_);
push @separated1, $separated[0];
push @separated2, $separated[1];
push @separated3, $separated[2];
}
$counter++

print "separated1 = @separated1\n";
print "separated2 = @separated2\n";
print "separated3 = @separated3\n";
```

Result that I got;

> separated1 = aaa
>
> separated2 = 111
>
> separated3 = AAA

Desired Result;

> separated1 = aaa bbb ccc ddd
>
> separated2 = 111 222 333 444
>
> separated3 = AAA BB CCC DD

Comment: actually you dont use your $counter variable. you increment it, but never access it. i guess you wanted to use it as index for your arrays.

Comment: This line:

`my @values = "aaa 111 AAA bbb 222 BBB ccc 333 CCC ddd 444 DDD"`

... is assigning one scalar value to an array. It's effectivly putting that scalar value into the first slot of `@value` array. You may do a `split` here directly:

`my @values = split / /,  "aaa 111 AAA bbb 222 BBB ccc 333 CCC ddd 444 DDD";`
Once this is in place, the rest is to take 3 values at a time etc etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rare ocassion where the C-style for loop is suitable, to iterate over every 3rd element

```
my $string = 'aaa 111 AAA bbb 222 BBB ccc 333 CCC ddd 444 DDD';

my (@sep1, @sep2, @sep3);

my @values = split ' ', $string;

for (my $i=0; $i <= $#values; $i += 3) {
    push @sep1, $values[$i];
    push @sep2, $values[$i+1];
    push @sep3, $values[$i+2];
}
```

This assumes that the array indeed has all triplets, or better check each element.

But it's normally far nicer to work with a single structure than with a set of parallel arrays. For example, use an array with elements that are array references

```
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

my @sep;

for (my $i=0; $i <= $#values; $i += 3) { 
    for my $j (0..2) { 
        push @{$sep[$j]}, $values[$i+$j]; 
    }
}

dd \@sep;
```

where the double iteration can be avoided with a much cleaner

```
for my $i (0..$#values) { 
    push @{$sep[$i%3]}, $values[$i] 
}
```

which replaces the two loops.

This prints

```
[
  ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"],
  [111, 222, 333, 444],
  ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"],
]
```

I use [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) to see complex data. An alternative in the core is [Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html).

---

And then there are many modules with all kinds of utility routines for work with lists.

For example, using [part](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#part-BLOCK-LIST) from [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) to partition the `@values` array

```
my @sep = map { [ @values[@$_] ] } part { $_%3 } 0..$#values;
```

This produces the same `@sep` with arrayrefs as above.

The `part` returns a list of arrayrefs, each containing indices since it partitioned the list of indices of `@values`. Then in [map](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) each arrayref is evaluated into its list of indices (`@$_`), which is used to take the corresponding slice of `@values`; that list is used to make an arrayref with `[]`. So `map` returns a list of arrayrefs, with values partitioned as needed.

For working with references please see tutorial [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and reference [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)

Answer (score 4):

```
my ( @foos, @bars, @quxs );
my @values = split(' ', $input);
while (@values) {
   push @foos, shift(@values);
   push @bars, shift(@values);
   push @quxs, shift(@values);
}
```

The above can also be written as follows:

```
my ( @foos, @bars, @quxs );
for ( my @values = split(' ', $input); @values; ) {
   push @foos, shift(@values);
   push @bars, shift(@values);
   push @quxs, shift(@values);
}
```

---

Are you sure you want parallel arrays, though? While they can save memory, it's usually hard to work with them, and more error-prone. In an object-dominated landscape, they are virtually never seen.

You could use an AoA:

```
my @moos;
my @values = split(' ', $input);
while (@values) {
   push @moos, [ splice(@values, 0, 3) ];
}
```

You could use an AoH:

```
my @moos;
my @values = split(' ', $input);
while (@values) {
   my %moo; @moo{qw( foo bar qux )} = splice(@values, 0, 3);
   push @moos, \%moo;
}
```

Comment: The first solution will put undefined values in the results if the number of items in the original `$values` is not divisable by 3.

Comment: @Silvar, That's intentional, so it's would be better to point out that the AoA solution doesn't do that.

Answer (score 3):

Another version using `part` from the non-core but very useful [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) module, that partitions up the elements directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say state/;
use List::MoreUtils qw/part/;

my $str = "aaa 111 AAA bbb 222 BBB ccc 333 CCC ddd 444 DDD";

my ($sep1, $sep2, $sep3) = part { state $i = 0; $i++ % 3 } split(' ', $str);

say "sep1: @$sep1";
say "sep2: @$sep2";
say "sep3: @$sep3";
```

prints out

```
sep1: aaa bbb ccc ddd
sep2: 111 222 333 444
sep3: AAA BBB CCC DDD
```

The magic here is with [state](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html), which ends up creating a variable local to the block it's in that retains its value across multiple evaluations of the block.

Answer (score 3):

Another job for [List::UtilsBy](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::UtilsBy 'bundle_by', 'unzip_by';

my $string = 'aaa 111 AAA bbb 222 BBB ccc 333 CCC ddd 444 DDD';
my @vals = split ' ', $string;
my ($sep1, $sep2, $sep3) = unzip_by { @$_ } bundle_by { [@_] } 3, @vals;

print "sep1: @$sep1\nsep2: @$sep2\nsep3: @$sep3\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/nU68Ck/1) might help you to get your desired results:

```
([a-z]+\s)([0-9]+\s)([A-Z]+)
```

It has three capturing groups for each of your desired results. You can add or reduce boundaries to it, as you wish, and it might be faster than other methods.

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Test

```js
const regex = /([a-z]+\s)([0-9]+\s)([A-Z]+)/gm;
const str = `aaa 111 AAA bbb 222 BBB ccc 333 CCC ddd 444 DDD`;
const subst = `\n$1 & $2 & $3\n`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### Perl Test

You can simply use `$1`, `$2` and `$3` and separate your data:

```
use strict;

my $str = 'aaa 111 AAA bbb 222 BBB ccc 333 CCC ddd 444 DDD';
my $regex = qr/([a-z]+\s)([0-9]+\s)([A-Z]+)/mp;
my $subst = '';

my $result = $str =~ s/$regex/$subst/rg;

print "The result of the substitution is' $result\n";
```

#### Performance Test

This JavaScript snippet shows the performance of that expression using a simple 1-million times `for` loop.

```js
const repeat = 1000000;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 const string = 'aaa 111 AAA bbb 222 BBB ccc 333 CCC ddd 444 DDD';
 const regex = /([a-z]+\s)([0-9]+\s)([A-Z]+)/gm;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "$1");
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the solutions from @ikegami and @zdim. @zdim's use of `part()` from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metaczapn.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) reminded me of `natatime`:

```
my @values = split(' ', "aaa 111 AAA bbb 222 BBB ccc 333 CCC ddd 444 DDD"); 
use List::MoreUtils 'natatime';              
my $nata_iter = natatime 3, @values ;
my @aoa ;           
while (my @tmp = $nata_iter->()) { push @aoa, \@tmp; };
```

Not really a consideration but possibly of interest: by using a temporary array (`@tmp`) to store the output of the iterator, the original `@values` remains intact whereas the more straightforward `splice()` is destructive.